# how to get the camera data

Tags: iphone

My app needs to get the camera data from Iphone.
In my ImagePickerController, there is overlayView drawing realtime indications.

I use UIGetScreenImage() to get the screenshot, and I also dump overlayview to image,
then I can restore the original Image based on these two images.

if the overlayView is still, it works quite well,
but if the overlayView  keeps changing, UIGetScreenImage() can not keep up with it.

For example,if the overlayView changes from a rectangle to a circle, then calling UIGetScreenImage() returns with a rectangle on top of it.

Is there a way to get the realtime camera data?
I really appreciate if someone could help.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand the question but if you want data from the overlay view you should just access the data from the properties of the overlay view itself. There is no reason to capture and image of the overlay just to get its data.